# order Array elements by Id and remove specific ones in Unity / C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an array that stores all my levels in a game. This array searches for all levels and

- orders them by their levelId
- removes the levels that are locked

So I go for this code

```
private Level[] levels;

private void Start()
{
    levels = FindObjectsOfType<Level>(); // find all levels
    levels = levels.OrderBy(currentLevel => currentLevel.Id).ToArray(); // order the array by levelId

    levels = levels.Where(currentLevel => currentLevel.IsUnlocked).ToArray(); // remove the locked levels from the array
}
```

Is there a better way to order the array and remove the locked levels?

Comment: You can compact this into one statement, first filter with `where` and then `orderby`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine thoose queries into one statement.

```
levels = FindObjectsOfType<Level>()
.Where(t=> t.IsUnlocked)
.OrderBy(currentLevel => currentLevel.Id)
.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably condense this into a single LINQ query expression:

```
levels = (from level in FindObjectsOfType<Level>()
          orderby level.Id
          where level.IsUnlocked
          select level).ToArray();
```

This looks much neater and reads quite naturally.

If you haven't come across these query expressions before, you can read about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/query-expression-basics).

Answer (score 1):

Let's put it this way:
We want to find all *unlocked* levels and order them by *Id*, needn't to sort the entire array of levels if we may need only a few of them.

It's also worth mentioning that `.ToArray()` forces immediate query evaluation and returns a new array.

You might want to do something along the lines of:

```
levels = 
     FindObjectsOfType<Level>()
     .Where(currentLevel => currentLevel.IsUnlocked)
     .OrderBy(currentLevel => currentLevel.Id)
     .ToArray();
```